# Open subset moduli space of parabolic vector bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, riemann-surfaces

Let $X$ be a connected, compact Riemann surface and let $p_1\dots p_k$ distinct points on it. We denote by $D$ the associated divisor. After the choice of so-called weight vectors $\alpha_i$ for each point $p_i$ and flag types $F_i$, one can build up the moduli space of semistable parabolic bundles of rank $r$, degree $\mathcal{M}$ with fixed flag types and weights.

The reference article I think is the following one by Seshadri and Mehta https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/291513528.pdf

Let us choose $d=0$:I've read somewhere that the points $x \in \mathcal{M}$ such that the corresponding parabolic vector bundle has the underlying structure of a trivial vector bundle constitues an open dense subset of $\mathcal{M}$. Where could I find a proof of this statement?

Comment: This is just the definition of a holomorphic vector bundle: It has to be locally (holomorphically) trivial.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't get how it should be related to the moduli space